# Protractor - Selenium doesn't find value for mobile but is in HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

So I had some issues when it comes to scraping with test cases for mobile. When I try to

```js
const orderNumber = element(by.css('[data-ft="order-number"]'))
const orderNumberText = await orderNumber.getText();
console.log(`Order Number: ${orderNumberText}`);
```

works fine for desktop but for mobile, it doesn't find it (Empty return of console.log) and I tried to print out the whole HTML DOM then the value is there.

```html
<div class="orderconfirmation-page">
  <h3 class="orderconfirmation-title">Thank you for your purchase.</h3>
  <div class="orderconfirmation-text">your order reference number:
    <span class="order-number" data-ft="order-number">7940700123456</span>
  </div>
```

and as I mentioned. with the code I posted before works perfectly with the desktop but as soon as I do through mobile then it doesn't find the value data-ft="order-number" but checking by the HTML DOM, it is there.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.getText()` returns a text value that is visible, so if you didn't scroll to element or the element overlapped, it returns an empty string.

In this case you need to go with `.getAttribute('innerText');`

```
const orderNumber = element(by.css('[data-ft="order-number"]'))
const orderNumberText = await orderNumber.getAttribute('innerText');
console.log(`Order Number: ${orderNumberText}`);
```

Try that and see if works

Comment: forgot to mention, unlike `.getAttribute('innerText')`, `.getText()` returns trimmed value. Might cause minor issues in some cases...